Basic CMakeLists.txt for OpenCV with Tesseract
Cannot build executable with the following CMakeLists.txt:

    cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.5 )

    project( TextExtract )

    find_package( PkgConfig REQUIRED )
    find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED)
    find_package( Tesseract REQUIRED )
    find_package( Leptonica REQUIRED )

    pkg_check_modules(tesseract REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET tesseract)
    pkg_check_modules(leptonica REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET lept)
    pkg_check_moduleS(libcurl REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libcurl)

    include_directories( ${Tesseract_INCLUDE_DIR} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

    link_directories( ${Tesseract_LIBRARY_DIR} ${OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIR} )

    file( GLOB source_files "*.cpp" )
    add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${source_files} )

    set_property(TARGET PkgConfig::tesseract APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES curl)
    target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        ${OpenCV_LIBS}
        PkgConfig::tesseract # With that linkage CMake will automatically add linkage with curl)

Error message (partial):
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libtesseract.a(equationdetectbase.cpp.o): in function     `tesseract::EquationDetectBase::RenderSpecialText(tesseract::Image, tesseract::BLOBNBOX*)':
equationdetectbase.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `pixGetDepth'
/usr/bin/ld: equationdetectbase.cpp:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `pixGetHeight'
/usr/bin/ld: equationdetectbase.cpp:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `boxCreate'
/usr/bin/ld: equationdetectbase.cpp:(.text+0xe9): undefined reference to `pixRenderBoxArb'
/usr/bin/ld: equationdetectbase.cpp:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `boxDestroy'
/usr/bin/ld: equationdetectbase.cpp:(.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `pixRenderBoxArb'
/usr/bin/ld: equationdetectbase.cpp:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `pixRenderBoxArb'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/TextExtract.dir/build.make:152: TextExtract] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/TextExtract.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
    *** Failure: Exit code 2 ***


Tried many variations of target_link_libraries directive but my understanding is poor. Need guidance on the minimal CMakeLists.txt to get Tesseract (built from source) to work under OpenCV. Thanks.
Code snippet:
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace tesseract;
...
    TessBaseAPI tess; // create Tesseract OCR instance
    if (tess.Init(nullptr, "eng", OEM_DEFAULT)) {
      cerr << "Tesseract initialization failed" << endl;
      return -3;
    }


Doesn't link to the tesseract library which is at /usr/local/lib
$ which tesseract
/usr/local/bin/tesseract
$ tesseract --version
tesseract 5.3.4-47-gd5e00
 leptonica-1.84.2
  libgif 5.2.1 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 2.1.5) : libpng 1.6.40 : libtiff 4.5.1 : zlib 1.2.13 : libwebp 1.2.4
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE4.1
 Found libarchive 3.6.2 zlib/1.2.13 liblzma/5.4.0 bz2lib/1.0.8 liblz4/1.9.4 libzstd/1.5.2
 Found libcurl/8.2.1 OpenSSL/3.0.10 zlib/1.2.13 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.5 libidn2/2.3.4 libpsl/0.21.2 (+libidn2/2.3.3) libssh/0.10.5/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.55.1 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.6.6


Which library is the pixGetDepth function from?

In your CMakeLists.txt you have searched for leptonica, but don't link with it. The symbols listed under "undefined reference" are defined by leptonica.

@drescherjm pixGetDepth is a public function of leptonica library. leptonica is a private dependency of tesseract.
Op, did you try find_package(Tesseract) then link to Tesseract::libtesseract? It might be more robust. tesseract pkgconfig file is well written, but I'm not sure that pkg_check_module in CMake properly understands Requires.private: lept in tesseract.pc.

Did you build these libraries as static libraries or shared?

Thanks, @Tsyvarev. That was the issue.

@drescherjm, using shared libraries. My ignorance was that I thought that libleptonica would be indirectly searched. Now I know better. Thanks everyone for helping out a first-time user.
